# Showing that the flow value is well defined.

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let $G$ be a directed graph with edge set $E$ and $u:E \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ a capacity function, as well as $x: E \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a function. Then $x$ is called an $s-t$ flow if the following properties are satisfied:

$(a)$ $x(e) \leq u(e)$ for all $e \in E$,

$(b)$ for all $v \in V - \{s,t\}$ it holds that: $\sum_{e \in \delta^{+}(v)} x(e)-\sum_{e \in \delta^{-}(v)} x(e)=0,$ where $\delta^+(v)$ denotes the edges that are starting in $v$ and $\delta^{-}(v)$ are the edges that are ending in $v$.

The flow value $v(x)$ is now defined as $v(x):=\sum_{e \in \delta^{+}(s)} x(e)-\sum_{e \in \delta^{-}(s)} x(e)$, or equivalently $v(x):=\sum_{e \in \delta^{+}(t)} x(e)-\sum_{e \in \delta^{-}(t)} x(e)$. My question is, why are those equivalent? My idea was to sum the equation in $(b)$ over all $v \in V - \{s,t\}$, giving $$0= \sum_{v \in V -\{s,t\}}(\sum_{e \in \delta^{+}(v)} x(e)-\sum_{e \in \delta^{-}(v)} x(e)) \iff v(x)=\sum_{v \in V -\{t\}}(\sum_{e \in \delta^{+}(v)} x(e)-\sum_{e \in \delta^{-}(v)} x(e)),$$ where I am using the first definition for $v(x)$. However, I don't know how to proceed, is this last expression equal to the other definition of $v(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sum over all vertices.

For simplicity, I adopt the notation $x(\delta^+(v))=\sum_{e\in \delta^+(v)}x(e)$ and analogously for $\delta^-(v)$ for any $v\in V$. We have

$$\sum_{v\in V}x(\delta^+(v))=\sum_{v\in V}x(\delta^-(v))$$
because every edge is ingoing exactly once and outgoing exactly once (i.e. every edge is counted exactly once on both sides).

Then essentially subtract what you have calculated:

$$\sum_{v\in V}x(\delta^+(v))-\sum_{v\neq s,t}(\delta^+(v))=\sum_{v\in V}x(\delta^-(v))-\sum_{v\neq s,t}(\delta^-(v))$$

This holds because $\sum_{v\neq s,t}(\delta^+(v))=\sum_{v\neq s,t}(\delta^-(v))$ by the second property. But this just means

$$\delta^+(s)+\delta^+(t)=\delta^-(s)+\delta^-(t)$$

which yields the result

$$\delta^+(s)-\delta^-(s)=\delta^-(t)-\delta^+(t)$$

by a simple arrangement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain where the first centered equality $\sum x(\delta^+(v))=\sum x(\delta^-(v))$ is coming from? I don't see why this should hold.

Comment: For every edge $e=(v,w)\in E$, the value $x(e)$ appears exactly once on the left hand side (in the sum $x(\delta^+(v))$) and exactly once on the right hand side (in the sum $x(\delta^-(w))$). These sums are just sums over edge flow values, so the equality must hold.

Comment: You should re-check your definition as it is not right. Take a path with unit flow, with endpoints $s$ and $t$ for example. Then $x(\delta^+(s))-x(\delta^-(s))=1$ but $x(\delta^+(t))-x(\delta^-(t))=-1$. It doesn't make sense for both source and sink to have more outgoing than ingoing (or vice versa), if you think about it.

Comment: You are right, which is what I just noticed. I will adapt the post. Thank you!